# Upgrading Mac OS X pre Leopard

Tags: macos, upgrade

I want to upgrade Xcode but it tells me I first need to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.6.6 (I have 10.5.8).

However, the links I find online all seem to expect me to use Leopard or Lion.

How to I get there (without buying something)?

Comment: P.S. 10.5.* is Leopard, 10.6.* is Snow Leopard, 10.7.* is Lion, and just for reference, 10.4.* is Tiger. Tiger is pre-Leopard.

Comment: See also: [Mac OS X Versions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. Due to the requirement of a 64-bit processor, a 64-bit OS, and the general evolution of requirements, much of Apple's software (and really, new software in general) simply reaches a point where you can't run newer versions without upgrading the OS, and occasionally your hardware, as a whole.